# C++: How to open IShellFolder drive folder from a shortcut

Tags: c++, windows, shell-extensions

I am using the following command in a shortcut to open my virtual drive in Windows Explorer.
%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe /e,::{MyExtension CLSID}

The virtual drive uses IShellFolder interface and is a ShellExtension. It has a couple of predefined folders in it.
The problem is that I can open the virtual drive in Windows explorer directly using the above statement but I cannot directly open one of its folders.

This link explains how to open a IShellFolder
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776817(VS.85).aspx#

but I am not sure how to use the objectname param
%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe /e,::{MyExtension CLSID},objectname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the [GMail Drive Shell extension](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/gmail.htm), installed it, and create a folder inside the namespace. Then I use the above method (/E,::{CLSID}) to create the shortcut and added ",foldername" at the end.
It worked perfectly, I think that you need to check your [IPersistFolder::Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931627.aspx) implementation.

Comment: Shay!! IS there any article that explains the correct way to implement the IPersistFolder::Initialize method? I want to recheck the implementation.

Comment: Check this: http://www.viksoe.dk/code/adfview.htm, someone wrote a shell namespace that impl Initialize() correctly.